# Meaning of commit and intense here

Tags: meaning

I'm writing something and there are a couple of things that I get mixed up.

> I'm **(committing / devoting)** too much time to preparing myself for getting a job. I'm kind of being **intense about** getting a job.

1. I think **devoting** is right, but I'd like to know if I could use **committing** here.
2. I think ***intense about something*** means giving too much energy about something, and that's why I used it in the sentence. but, I'm not sure exactly what ***intense*** means.

It would mean a lot to me, if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

That which has been **committed** has been promised or dedicated to a *future* endeavor. That which has been **devoted** has been already put to use.

If you *are committing time* to prepare for a job search, you are not searching for the job yet. The time has been identified as available for the search when it begins.

If you *are devoting time* to a job search, you are either searching for a job now, or planning to do such a search (since the present-tense can be used as an expression of future events).

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.... sorry..

Comment: Try reading it again. If you can pose your question, you can understand this answer.  Commitment looks to the future.  Devotion acts in the present.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. thank you, but how about "intense"? now matter how I tried to find it, I failed to get what I want.

Comment: Rolling two questions into one is not considered good practice here on ELL. You should ask about **being intense about** in a separate question

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will